# How to know who called an action of controller in symfony

Tags: symfony, routes, request

I'm working in a Symfony2 project, and i have an action of controller which is called from 2 different pages. how can i know which page called my action, so i can return a different Response according to who made the request :

here's the an example of what i wanna do

```
public function deleteAction(File $file)
    {
        // i delete the file

        if (// request made from first page) {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('route_of_first_page');
        }
        elseif (// request made from second page) {
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('route_of_second_page');
        }

    }
```

This way  i can stay in the page who made the request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need your action to have the request parameter:

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, File $file)
```

and then get the referer from the request object:

```
$previousUrl = $request->headers->get('referer');
```

**EDIT:**
To get the route object:

```
$router = $this->get('router');
$route = $router->match($previousUrl);
```

Comment: You could also use -- $request->server->get('HTTP_REFERER', $this->router->generate('default_route',array())) -- which would also let you set a default fallback if the referer is empty

Comment: Indeed, but I trust symfony more than I trust my server config :) The referer attribute is set explicitly by symfony.

Comment: i don't know why i doesn't work: i print the request variable and i see Referer attribute but when i print it to see if it's the correct url it doesn't print anything

Comment: i checked `$previousUrl` with var_dump and it has `null` value

Comment: You get the referer from the HEADERS not the ATTRIBUTES... my bad :(

Comment: now it works, thanks.
Is there a way to get the route associated with the url ?

Comment: it doesn't work, my route have 2 parameters: heres the definition of my route:

`envivioupload_upload:
    pattern:  /upload/{param1}/{param2}
    defaults: { _controller: EnvivioUploadBundle:Upload:delete }`

Comment: sometimes the `referrer` might not be set. You could use a kernel listener to store the last route in a session.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to have redirect included at the begining of the file

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
```

Then call it's constructor directly to redirect

```
return new RedirectResponse($request->server->get('HTTP_REFERER', $this->router->generate('default_route',array()) ));
```

The default route is optional